# Wide to long in python, with year repeating

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert this wide format of tables in pandas to:

```
       Jan  Feb Mar Apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
2019    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2020    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2021    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

in this format:

```
YEAR    MON dd

2019    DEC 0

2019    NOV 0

2019    OCT 0

2019    SEP 0

2019    AUG 0

2019    JUL 0

2019    JUN 0

2019    MAY 0

2019    APR 0

2019    MAR 0

2019    FEB 0

2019    JAN 0

2018    DEC 0
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

`df.transpose()` can make your columns the rows and your rows the columns.